# Why does this code compile?

Tags: c++

What are the exact rules for deciding the access rights for the objects nested into the private sections of other objects?

For example, in the code snipped below, the `proxy_t` struct is nested into the private section of the `abc_t`, and yet its methods are available to the `main` function. Why does it compile at all?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <valarray>

using namespace std;

class abc_t{
  private: 
    struct proxy_t{
      proxy_t operator()(double& a, double& b){ __a=a; __b=b; return *this; }
      double a(){ return __a; }
      double b(){ return __b; }
      private:
        double __a, __b;
    };

  public:
    abc_t( const size_t N ){ 
       _a.resize(N,-101.); 
       _b.resize(N,-202.);  
    }
    double a(size_t j){ return _a[j]; }
    double b(size_t j){ return _b[j]; }

    proxy_t operator[](const size_t j) { return _proxy(_a[j],_b[j]); }

  private:
    valarray<double> _a;
    valarray<double> _b;
    proxy_t _proxy;
};


int main(){
 size_t n_elem=10;
 abc_t abc(n_elem);
 cout<<"direct: "<< abc.a(1)<<"  "<<abc.b(1)<<"\n";
 cout<<"proxied:"<<abc[1].a()<<"  "<<abc[1].b()<<"\n";  // ain't proxy_t::aa() private?
 //cout<<abc[1]; // doomed to fail
}
```

Comment: gnu, intel, pgi, Visual Studio Express 2010 C++

Comment: Don't know, but those uses of double underscores are illegal.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This line is the important one that I'm gonna talk about:

```
cout<<"proxied:"<<abc[1].a()<<"  "<<abc[1].b()<<"\n";
```

When you call abc[1], this is a public method of abc_t. This is valid.

It returns a proxy_t. Although the declaration of this class (proxy_t) is not defined, you aren't actually using that return variable to create a new object. If you were to do the following, it wouldn't compile.

```
proxy_t p = abc[1];
```

It crashes with that because proxy_t is being declared, you are initializing a new object, however that type doesn't exist in that scope. Since you aren't actually declaring any variables of that type, nothing of proxy_t is being created in that scope (which would be illegal).

By proxy_t being private, that simply means you can't create any objects of that type anywhere except from within the abc_t class. However, it's being passed as a return value, which is valid -- no objects are being created/instantiated/declared, just an existing one is being passed.

Then the fun part. With classes, everything by default is private (unless specified otherwise). With structs, **everything by default is public**. Therefore, proxy_t::a() is public, and therefore CAN be used in main because main happens to have access to a proxy_t object.

Comment: "If you were to say the following, it would crash". You must've meant it won't compile.

Comment: @arasmussen: What gets me puzzled is this: naively, I'd expect that abc[1].a() is equivalent to using _proxy.a() method in the main() function, and the latter is clearly illegal.

Comment: @Zhenya: Since abc[1] returns a proxy_t, and you aren't instantiating anything of type proxy_t, it's legal. You just can't instantiate anything of type "proxy_t" in that scope. In your case, you aren't, you're simply calling a public method on an object that exists elsewhere.

Comment: @arasmussen: and the fact that this elsewhere is a private area of the abc_t does not matter, is this what you're saying?

Comment: @Zhenya - It is much like a function  returning a reference to the class' private data. You can use it, once the class has given you access to it, but not gain access yourself.

Answer (score 1):

You have defined the struct proxy_t as private, but the actual methods it exposes are public. My guess is that your compiler will not allow you to directly instantiate a proxy_t struct in main, but if you return one from class abc_t, it will allow you to call public methods on it.

Perhaps someone who knows the C++ standard can comment if this is correct behaviour for a compiler or not.

Answer (score 0):

You're saying abc[1].a() which says go here:

```
proxy_t operator[](const size_t j) { return _proxy(_a[j],_b[j]); }
```

which is public and throws that 1 in for j.  Then it returns

```
_proxy(_a[j],_b[j])
```

which is calling the private struct that you use to access the a() function

Answer (score 0):

Since `proxy_t` is a private member to `abc_t`, no one except `abc_t` can use it (i.e. instantiate objects of this type). However, given an existing `proxy_t`, everybody can invoke its members - because they are public.

The standard is a bit dull here (or I'm looking at the wrong place), but this is my best finding (11.8):

> A nested class is a member and as such has the same access rights as any other member. The members of
>   an enclosing class have no special access to members of a nested class; the usual access rules (Clause 11)
>   shall be obeyed.

Reading between the lines: Since a nested class is 'just' a member, usual access control is applied when somebody refers to this type (i.e. spells out `proxy_t`). But for access to members of `proxy_t` itself, no special access rules apply - if you managed to get a `proxy_t` object from a privileged source, you can access its members as if it wasn't a nested class.

Comment: What gets me puzzled is this: naively, I'd expect that abc[1].a() is equivalent to using _proxy.a() method in the main() function, and the latter is clearly illegal. Furthermore, if proxy_t is 'just' a member of an abc_t, it's a private one. How come its members are exposed?